# Non-linear Least Squares Fitting (2-dimensional) in Python

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, linear-algebra

I was wondering what the correct approach to fitting datapoints to a non-linear function should be in python.

I am trying to fit a series of data-points

```
t = [0., 0.5, 1., 1.5, ...., 4.]
y = [6.3, 4.5,.................]
```

using the following model function

```
f(t, x) = x1*e^(x2*t)
```

I was mainly wondering which library routine is appropriate for this problem and how it should be setup. I tried using the following with unsuccessful results:

```
t_data = np.array([0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0,........])
y_data = np.array([6.8, 3., 1.5, 0.75........])

def func_nl_lsq(x, t, y):
    return [x[0]*np.exp(x[1]*t)] -  y

popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(func_nl_lsq, t_data, y_data)
```

I know it's unsuccessful because I am able to solve the "equivalent" linear least squares problem (simply obtained by taking the log of the model function) and its answer doesn't even come close to the one I am getting by doing the above.

Thank you

Comment: Generally, fits to the log of the model will not match fits to the model because fits to the log version will actually assign much more relative weight to points with small y-values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are using the wrong function. Your function `func_nl_lsq` calculates the residual, it is not the model function. To use `scipy.otimize.curve_fit`, you have to define model function, as answers by @DerWeh and @saullo_castro suggest. You still can use custom residual function as you like with `scipy.optimize.least_squares` instead of `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`.

```
t_data = np.array([0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0])
y_data = np.array([6.8, 3., 1.5, 0.75])

def func_nl_lsq(x, t=t_data, y=y_data):
    return x[0]*np.exp(x[1]*t) -  y
    # removed one level of []'s

scipy.optimize.least_squares(func_nl_lsq, [0, 0])
```

Also, please note, that the remark by @MadPhysicist is correct: the two problems you are considering (the initial problem and the problem where model function is under logarithm) are not equivalent to each other. Note that if you apply logarithm to your model function, you apply it also to the residuals, and *residual sum of squares* now means something different. This lead to different optimization problem and different results.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `curve_fit` you can simplify it quite a bit, with no need to compute the error inside your function:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t_data = np.array([0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.])
y_data = np.array([6.8, 3., 1.5, 0.75, 0.25, 0.1])
def func_nl_lsq(t, *args):
    a, b = args
    return a*np.exp(b*t)
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func_nl_lsq, t_data, y_data, p0=[1, 1])
plt.plot(t_data, y_data, 'o')
plt.plot(t_data, func_nl_lsq(t_data, *popt), '-')
plt.show()
```

### EDIT

Note I'm using a general signature that accepts `*args`. In order for this to work you must pass `p0` to `curve_fit`.

The conventional approach is shown below:

```
def func_nl_lsq(t, a, b):
    return a*np.exp(b*t)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func_nl_lsq, t_data, y_data)
a, b = popt
plt.plot(t_data, func_nl_lsq(t_data, a, b), '-')
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Seems like a great and concise solution! If I use your same exact code, I get the following: `ValueError: Unable to determine number of fit parameters.` on the `curve_fit` call. Any ideas why that is?

Comment: @user3501476 sure..  I am using a general approach where `*args` is passed instead of `a, b`. In order to use this approach `curve_fit` needs to receive `p0` with the desired number of unknowns. I've edited the answer (I created the curve here with the updated code)

Answer (score 0):

`scipy.otimize.curve_fit` can be used to fit the data. I think you just don't use it properly. I assume you have a given `t` and `y` and try to fit a function of the form `x1*exp(x2*t) = y`.

You need

```
ydata = f(xdata, *params) + eps
```

This means your function is not defined properly. Your function should look like probably look like

```
def func_nl_lsq(t, x1, x2):
    return x1*np.exp(x2*t)
```

depending what you really want to fit. Here x1 and x2 are your fitting parameter. It is also possible to do

```
def func_nl_lsq(t, x):
    return x[0]*np.exp(x[1]*t)
```

but you likely need to provide an initial guess p0.