# Bounding parameter search range in nonlinear least-square fitting in GSL

Tags: c++, curve-fitting, gsl

I'm interested in performing a non-linear least-square fitting of a custom function using GSL Nonlinear Least-Squares Fitting routines.

In previous posts, I showed (with the crucial help of other users) how to fix a parameter of a custom function during the fitting procedure, while allowing the estimation of other parameters.

Now, I am interested in finding a way to limit the parameter search range over a specific interval. The reason for that is that I would like to avoid local maxima in 'wrong' regions of the parameter space.

Below is an implementation of the GSL routines, using a C++ wrapper (as detailed in [Nonlinear least-squares fitting with two independent variables in C++: implementing GSL algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72914352/nonlinear-least-squares-fitting-with-two-independent-variables-in-c-implement)):

```
template <typename F, size_t... Is>
auto gen_tuple_impl(F func, std::index_sequence<Is...> )
{
    return std::make_tuple(func(Is)...);
}

template <size_t N, typename F>
auto gen_tuple(F func)
{
    return gen_tuple_impl(func, std::make_index_sequence<N>{} );
}

template <class R, class... ARGS>
struct function_ripper {
    static constexpr size_t n_args = sizeof...(ARGS);
};

template <class R, class... ARGS>
auto constexpr n_params(R (ARGS...) )
{
    return function_ripper<R, ARGS...>();
}


auto internal_solve_system(gsl_vector* initial_params, gsl_multifit_nlinear_fdf *fdf,
             gsl_multifit_nlinear_parameters *params) -> std::vector<double>
{
  // This specifies a trust region method
  const gsl_multifit_nlinear_type *T = gsl_multifit_nlinear_trust;
  const size_t max_iter = 200;
  const double xtol = 1.0e-8;
  const double gtol = 1.0e-8;
  const double ftol = 1.0e-8;

  auto *work = gsl_multifit_nlinear_alloc(T, params, fdf->n, fdf->p);
  int info;

  // initialize solver
  gsl_multifit_nlinear_init(initial_params, fdf, work);
  //iterate until convergence
  gsl_multifit_nlinear_driver(max_iter, xtol, gtol, ftol, nullptr, nullptr, &info, work);

  // result will be stored here
  gsl_vector * y    = gsl_multifit_nlinear_position(work);
  auto result = std::vector<double>(initial_params->size);

  for(int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++)
  {
    result[i] = gsl_vector_get(y, i);
  }

  auto niter = gsl_multifit_nlinear_niter(work);
  auto nfev  = fdf->nevalf;
  auto njev  = fdf->nevaldf;
  auto naev  = fdf->nevalfvv;

  // nfev - number of function evaluations
  // njev - number of Jacobian evaluations
  // naev - number of f_vv evaluations
  //logger::debug("curve fitted after ", niter, " iterations {nfev = ", nfev, "} {njev = ", njev, "} {naev = ", naev, "}");

  gsl_multifit_nlinear_free(work);
  gsl_vector_free(initial_params);
  return result;
}

template<auto n>
auto internal_make_gsl_vector_ptr(const std::array<double, n>& vec) -> gsl_vector*
{
    auto* result = gsl_vector_alloc(vec.size());
    int i = 0;
    for(const auto e: vec)
    {
        gsl_vector_set(result, i, e);
        i++;
    }
    return result;
}


template<typename C1>
struct fit_data
{
    const std::vector<double>& t;
    const std::vector<double>& y;
    // the actual function to be fitted
    C1 f;
};


template<typename FitData, int n_params>
int internal_f(const gsl_vector* x, void* params, gsl_vector *f)
{
    auto* d  = static_cast<FitData*>(params);
    // Convert the parameter values from gsl_vector (in x) into std::tuple
    auto init_args = [x](int index)
    {
        return gsl_vector_get(x, index);
    };
    auto parameters = gen_tuple<n_params>(init_args);

    // Calculate the error for each...
    for (size_t i = 0; i < d->t.size(); ++i)
    {
        double ti = d->t[i];
        double yi = d->y[i];
        auto func = [ti, &d](auto ...xs)
        {
            // call the actual function to be fitted
            return d->f(ti, xs...);
        };
        auto y = std::apply(func, parameters);
        gsl_vector_set(f, i, yi - y);
    }
    return GSL_SUCCESS;
}

using func_f_type   = int (*) (const gsl_vector*, void*, gsl_vector*);
using func_df_type  = int (*) (const gsl_vector*, void*, gsl_matrix*);
using func_fvv_type = int (*) (const gsl_vector*, const gsl_vector *, void *, gsl_vector *);

template<auto n>
auto internal_make_gsl_vector_ptr(const std::array<double, n>& vec) -> gsl_vector*;


auto internal_solve_system(gsl_vector* initial_params, gsl_multifit_nlinear_fdf *fdf,
             gsl_multifit_nlinear_parameters *params) -> std::vector<double>;

template<typename C1>
auto curve_fit_impl(func_f_type f, func_df_type df, func_fvv_type fvv, gsl_vector* initial_params, fit_data<C1>& fd) -> std::vector<double>
{
    assert(fd.t.size() == fd.y.size());

    auto fdf = gsl_multifit_nlinear_fdf();
    auto fdf_params = gsl_multifit_nlinear_default_parameters();

    fdf.f   = f;
    fdf.df  = df;
    fdf.fvv = fvv;
    fdf.n   = fd.t.size();
    fdf.p   = initial_params->size;
    fdf.params = &fd;

    // "This selects the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm with geodesic acceleration."
    fdf_params.trs = gsl_multifit_nlinear_trs_lmaccel;
    return internal_solve_system(initial_params, &fdf, &fdf_params);
}


template <typename Callable, auto n>
auto curve_fit(Callable f, const std::array<double, n>& initial_params, const std::vector<double>& x, const std::vector<double>& y) -> std::vector<double>
{
    // We can't pass lambdas without convert to std::function.
    //constexpr auto n = 3;//decltype(n_params(f))::n_args - 5;
    //constexpr auto n = 2;
    assert(initial_params.size() == n);

    auto params = internal_make_gsl_vector_ptr(initial_params);
    auto fd = fit_data<Callable>{x, y, f};
    return curve_fit_impl(internal_f<decltype(fd), n>, nullptr, nullptr, params,  fd);
}
```

The custom function to be fitted is a `gaussian`:

```
double gaussian(double x, double b, double a, double c)
    {
        const double z = (x - b) / c;
        return a * std::exp(-0.5 * z * z);
    }

struct gaussian_fixed_a
{
    double a;
    gaussian_fixed_a(double a) : a{a} {}
    double operator()(double x, double b, double c) const { return gaussian(x, b, a, c); }
};
```

And these last lines show how I would create a fake dataset of observed data (with some noise which is normally distributed) and test the fitting curve function with two independent variables, given by the vectors `xs` and `bs`.

```
    int main()
    {
        auto device = std::random_device();
        auto gen    = std::mt19937(device());
    
        auto xs = linspace<std::vector<double>>(0.0, 1.0, 300);
        auto bs = linspace<std::vector<double>>(0.4, 1.4, 300);
        auto ys = std::vector<double>(xs.size());
    
        double a = 5.0, c = 0.15;
    
        for(size_t i = 0; i < xs.size(); i++)
        {

            auto y =  gaussian(xs[i], a, bs[i], c);
            auto dist  = std::normal_distribution(0.0, 0.1 * y);
            ys[i] = y + dist(gen);
        }
        gaussian_fixed_a g(a);
        auto r = curve_fit(g, std::array{0.11}, xs, bs, ys);
    
        std::cout << "result: " << r[0] << ' ' << '\n';
        std::cout << "error : " << r[0] - c << '\n';
    
    }
```

My understanding of a the problem is that I should probably find a way to define boundaries in the trust region of the numerical optimisation. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

I spent some time trying to find a way to set limits on the curve fit parameters and I was unable to find any gsl function to set a limit.  Nevertheless, I did manage to find a way to set the limits in the fit function definition... Using some simplified code to illustrate...  In the example below are the function for A*Exp(B*X)+C and the derivative of the function.  In both, there is a test to see if parameter C is greater than 1.  If it is greater than one then the parameter and the vector element is changed to the value of 1.  This does work but I don't know if this is really the best way to solve this problem.

Also note that for more generality, the limits for each parameter would be fed to the function using (in my example) the FN_Params structure.

```
int Fn_Exp_C(const gsl_vector * gx, void *data, gsl_vector *gsl_v)
{
  FN_Params *Fnp = (FN_Params *) data;

  size_t n = Fnp->n;
  double *x = Fnp->x;
  double *y = Fnp->y;

  double A = gsl_vector_get(gx, 0);
  double B = gsl_vector_get(gx, 1);
  double C = gsl_vector_get(gx, 2);
//*********************************************
//Limit C<=1    
  if(C > 1)
  {
      C = 1;
      gsl_vector_set((gsl_vector*) gx, 2, 1);
  }
//*********************************************  

  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    double dx = x[i];
    double Yi =A*exp(dx*B)+C;
    gsl_vector_set(gsl_v, i, Yi - y[i]);
  }
  return GSL_SUCCESS;
}

int Fn_Exp_C_d(const gsl_vector * gx, void *data, gsl_matrix * gsl_m)
{
  FN_Params *Fnp = (FN_Params *) data;

  size_t n = Fnp->n;
  double *x = Fnp->x;
  double *y = Fnp->y;

  double A = gsl_vector_get(gx, 0);
  double B = gsl_vector_get(gx, 1);
  double C = gsl_vector_get(gx, 2);
//*********************************************
//Limit C<=1    
  if(C > 1)
  {
      C = 1;
      gsl_vector_set((gsl_vector*) gx, 2, 1);
  }
//*********************************************    
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    double dx = x[i];
  
    gsl_matrix_set(gsl_m, i, 0, exp(dx*B)); 
    gsl_matrix_set(gsl_m, i, 1, (A*dx*exp(dx*B)));
    gsl_matrix_set(gsl_m, i, 2, 1); 
  }
  return GSL_SUCCESS;
}
```