# Non-Linear Least Square Fitting Using Python

Tags: python, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to find the optimal parameter values based on 2 dimensional data.

I searched for other Q&A threads and one of the questions looked similar to mine and the answer seemed to be duable [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40046961/non-linear-least-squares-fitting-2-dimensional-in-python) for me to replicate but I get the following error:  
`TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

I rarely changed the codes but customized a bit only but seems like my equation does not accept Numpy arrays. Is there a way to address this issue and derive the parameter values?

 Below is the code:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t_data = np.array([0,5,10,15,20,25,27])
y_data = np.array([1771,8109,22571,30008,40862,56684,59101])

def func_nl_lsq(t, *args):
    K, A, L, b = args
    return math.exp(L*x)/((K+A*(b**x)))

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func_nl_lsq, t_data, y_data, p0=[1, 1, 1, 1])
plt.plot(t_data, y_data, 'o')
plt.plot(t_data, func_nl_lsq(t_data, *popt), '-')
plt.show()
print(popt[0], popt[1], popt[2], popt[3])
```

For more clarifications, I also attach a screenshot of the (1) equation that I want to run NLS fitting and the data observations from the [journal paper](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/isre.1.1.23) that I've read.

[image] ... (1)

| year(x_data) | value(y_data) |
| --- | --- |
| 1960 | 1771 |
| 1965 | 8109 |
| 1970 | 22571 |
| 1975 | 30008 |
| 1980 | 40862 |
| 1985 | 56684 |
| 1987 | 59101 |

Comment: Hey Todd, thanks for the clear question, just one thing, what is the `x` in `return math.exp(L*x)/((K+A*(b**x)))`? I cannot run the code without its value (also you forgot `import math` at the top)

Comment: Also the function `func_nl_lsq` ignores the argument `t`, this looks like a bug

Comment: The code runs if I set `x = t` and use `np.exp` instead of `math.exp` but the result is still not great

Comment: Ok I think I fixed your code, please take a look at my answer

Comment: They are four parameters  in your equation but only seven experimental points. It is not sufficient to expect a reliable result. More over the curve is quite linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so there was quite some work to do:

- Set `x = t` (probably a typo)
- Use `np.exp` instead of `math.exp`. `np.exp` is also used in the docs: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html
- Change the initial guesses to `0.1` as nonlinear optimization is sensible to initial guesses. Take care to choose guesses as near as possible to your ballpark estimate of the parameters order of magnitude. If you cannot estimate, run the fitting algorithm many times for many initial guesses, then you can select the (non-failed) fit with the smallest sum of residuals squared, see here learn how to calculate those residuals: [Getting the r-squared value using curve_fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189362/getting-the-r-squared-value-using-curve-fit)

Here is the final result:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

t_data = np.array([0,5,10,15,20,25,27])
y_data = np.array([1771,8109,22571,30008,40862,56684,59101])

def func_nl_lsq(t, *args):
    K, A, L, b = args
    x=t # typo on your part?
    exponential = np.exp(L*x) # np.exp rather than math.exp
    denominator = K+A*(b**x)
    return exponential/denominator

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func_nl_lsq, t_data, y_data, p0=[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]) # changed initial conditions
plt.plot(t_data, y_data, 'o')
plt.plot(t_data, func_nl_lsq(t_data, *popt), '-')
plt.show()
print(popt[0], popt[1], popt[2], popt[3])
```

With output:

```
7.36654485198494e-05 0.0011449352764853055 0.05547299686499709 0.5902083262954019
```

And plot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, Caridorc. You rescued me from where I was struggling. I learned a lot, especially choosing good initial guess set seems very important. My guess such as 1,1,1,1 was not even fitting to the data points at all. Thanks, again.

Comment: You are welcome @Todd , good luck in your data analysis journey!